# Applescript: Get the file path without the file name, from a word document, but the result is empty

Tags: ms-word, applescript

I am trying to get the file path, without the file name, from the front document on Word, from Applescript, but what I have is an empty string.

Here is the code from MacScripter.

```
Tell application "Microsoft Word"
  activate
  tell front document
    --full path and file name
    set TheName to get full name as string
    display dialog TheName
    --File path
    set ThePath to get file path as string
    display dialog ThePath
  end tell
end tell
```

`TheName` comes perfect. The path and the file name but `ThePath` comes empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Word provides only the full path. Use `System Events` to get the parent folder

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set filePath to path of front document
end tell
tell application "System Events" to set parentFolder to path of (container of disk item filePath)
```